# What is the formula for the set of normal vectors to a level curve (of arbitrary dimension)?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose $G : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function and the level set $L = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: G(x)=0 \}$ is an $n-1$ dimentional surface near the point $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$. Then the gradient $\nabla G(x_0)$ determines the subspace of all vectors perpendicular to $L$ at $x_0$.

In general $L$ might be some $m<n$ dimensional surface near $x_0$. In that case $\nabla G(x_0)$ does not determine he subspace of all vectors perpendicular to $L$. For example $G(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2$ has the $z$-axis as a level set. At each point the normal vectors are all vectors in the $xy$-plane. While $\nabla G = (x,y,0)$ is in that plane it does not determine it.

What is the formula for the set of perpendicular vectors at  point of a level surface, if we impose no restrictions on the dimensions?

Comment: The function $G(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2$ has rotational symmetric level sets (the sets $G= t>0$) which are parallel to the $z$-axis. For these the gradient is normal to the levels. The case $G=0$ is a singularity, in which the gradient vanishes.

Comment: Yep, the gradient is normal to the levels, but there are loads of other normal vectors too and that's the problem!